# What's your input on /input?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/input) has at least two unrelated meanings:

- Input devices (keyboard, mouse, etc.), in particular device-independent event mechanisms, e.g. [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202229/how-to-get-the-mouse-keyboard-raw-events) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198179/usb-bar-code-scanner-not-working-on-raspbian)
- Input to a program, e.g. [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202113/when-does-cat-finish-reading-from-a-pipe) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193602/how-many-bytes-can-a-keypress-return-and-should-a-metafied-key-return-more)

That second category is a bit fuzzy. It overlaps with [stdin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stdin).

We also have [tag:output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/output), which is mostly the pendant of the second category, and its companion [stdout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stdout) (plus [stderr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stderr) but that's a more useful tag).

I propose to rename the input device meaning to [input-device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/input-device). I'm not sure what to do about the program input meaning and about [output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/output).

Comment: I agree too. I'm be inclined to drop the /output tag as well unless there's a compelling reason to keep it.

Comment: @slm, what about braille tty, video, seat shakers and whatnot?

Comment: @hildred - can you elaborate? I don't understand what those have to do with /output.

Comment: they are output devices that may not be directly associated with stdout, much as a mouse is a input device not associated with stdin. just food for thought.

Answer (score 7):

As regards `/input`, I second moving it to `/input-device`.

As for `/output`, how about simply making it a synonym of `/stdout`? That seems to be the most frequent usage.